# Need help with VPN and Orbot

Tags: orbot

I downloaded a free VPN, but when I downloaded Orbot the Orbot browser does not work.

I have a kindle fire HD. I read related topics on this website but nothing works for me.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Does orbot work without the VPN?

Answer (score 1):

There are two apps that are required to access tor with Android. You need the Orbot, a tor proxy, and a browser that is configured to use the socks proxy it creates. Two browser are configured to work with Orbot are orfox and orweb, orfox is newer and based on Firefox and would be my recommendation. I think orweb is available on Fdroid and it might no longer be maintained.

As for the VPN, I do not recommend any free VPN for any privacy what so ever!